# unset "password_again" from sfGuardUserAdminForm

Tags: forms, symfony-1.4, backend

I tried to unset the widget "password_again" from the sfGuardUserAdminForm on the backend app. But nothing works.

I try to not-displaying in the generator.yml file

```
form:
    class: sfGuardUserAdminForm
    display:
      "User":                   [first_name, last_name, email_address, username]
      "Permissions and groups": [is_active, is_super_admin, groups_list, permissions_list]
```

But the field stills appears in the form.
And I try to unset on the form configure
    unset($this['password_again']);

But an error appears
    Widget "password_again" does not exist.

Comment: How are you rendering your form? It seems that you try to render the password_again field (and it does not exist, because you unset it)

Answer (score 0):

In **/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/form/doctrine/base/BasesfGuardUserAdminForm.class.php**
Comment  next line

```
//  $this->widgetSchema['password_again'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword();
//    $this->validatorSchema['password_again'] = clone $this->validatorSchema['password'];
//
//    $this->widgetSchema->moveField('password_again', 'after', 'password');
//
//    $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password_again', array(), array('invalid' => 'The two passwords must be the same.')));
```

In **sfGuardUserAdminForm.class.php**

```
unset($this['password_again']);
```

And del it from generator.yml

Comment: Did you del "pasword_again" from /plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/modules/sfGuardUser/config/generator.yml? Do you have sfGuardUser module in apps/backen/modules? It work for me

Comment: I clone the sfGuardUser module in my backend, and the "password_again" deleted from that generator.yml file, but not from plugins folder. It works only if I del from plugins folder.... not seems to be very scalable or maintanable

Comment: But it works)I do not recommend deleting the field, sometimes the user can make a mistake when enters the password, this field can reduce the risk of errors.

Comment: Thats the point... What to do if I need the field on other module? It works but its only a patch. Still, thanks